# httpd not starting when Tomcat is running

Tags: tomcat, httpd, systemd

I observe a problem when using Apache's httpd and Tomcat on CentOS 7. Both are running on the same host, both installed from official repositories. httpd does SAML with mod_auth_mellon and proxies to the backend web app, running in Tomcat.

Initial situation:

1. Both services are stopped

First use case:

1. systemctl start httpd
2. systemctl start tomcat
3. --> works

Second use case:

1. systemctl start tomcat
2. systemctl start httpd
3. --> does NOT work

Error message:

```
Aug 09 14:03:08 prod2.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
Aug 09 14:03:09 prod2.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 09 14:03:09 prod2.localdomain kill[55952]: kill: cannot find process ""
Aug 09 14:03:09 prod2.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 09 14:03:09 prod2.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Aug 09 14:03:09 prod2.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Aug 09 14:03:09 prod2.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

There are no port collisions, checked it with `netstat -nalp`. httpd is only bound to port 80, tomcat only to 8080 and 8009.

Therefore two questions:

1. What does systemd try to kill?
2. What is happening?

Comment: This is propably related to logging. httpd reloads after logrotate. If Tomcat is running, reload fails.

Answer (score 0):

Anything in the error_log? Also check /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service/httpd.service settings in systemd. Maybe there is a dependency.

Comment: Hi! Nothing in the error logs, nothing special in  /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service, nothing in /etc/sysconfig/httpd

Comment: This is strange. I have the same setup with apache and tomcat in centos 7.3.  And I did the same start order with  no issues. Does journalctl -xe show any more messages? Maybe after stopping both services make sure they are really stopped. Also maybe start tomcat manually instead of via systemd? /usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh?